# is there a way to get the size of TFRecord file and the size of one Example in it?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, tfrecord

Because I want to get the number of Examples in a TFRecord file, the currently method I used is

```
len([x for x in tf.python_io.tf_record_iterator(tf_record_file)])
```

but it is slow.
All Examples in my TFRecord file have exactly the same length, so I wonder that if there is a way to get the size (the number of bytes) of whole TFRecord file (xxx.tfrecord) and the size (the number of bytes) of one Example in it? Then I think I can just use

> number_of_Examples = (length of TFRecord file) / (length of the first
>   Example) = (bytes of all Examples in xxx.tfrecord) / (bytes of one Expmale)

to get the number of Examples more quickly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A TFRecord file is essentially an array of `Example`s, and it does not include the number of examples as metadata. Thus, one must iterate over it to count the number of examples. Another option is saving the size as metadata on creation time (in some separate file).

### Edit:

The approach you propose won't work as long as 2 examples may be of different sizes, which is sometimes the case even if the number of features is identical.

If it is guaranteed that all examples have exactly the same number of bytes you could do the following:

```
import os
import sys
import tensorflow as tf

def getSize(filename):
    st = os.stat(filename)
    return st.st_size

file = "..."

example_size = 0
example = tf.train.Example()
for x in tf.python_io.tf_record_iterator(file):
    example.ParseFromString(x)
    example_size = example.ByteSize()
    break

file_size = getSize(file)
n = file_size / (example_size + 16)

print("file size in bytes:{}".format(file_size))
print("example size in bytes:{}".format(example_size))
print("N:{}".format(n))
```

Comment: sorry, I think you misunderstood me, I mean is there a way to calculate (bytes of all Examples in xxx.tfrecord) / (bytes of one Expmale)?

Comment: I assum that when you say 'all Examples in my TFRecord file have exactly the same length' you mean that the number of features is the same. If you mean so, and not that the exact memory footprint is identical, than no your approach won't work. The reason is that different examples may have different sizes even with same number of features and then the denominator 'bytes of one Expmale' is not a constant.

Comment: Yes, your code works as I expected. And there is a new problem, I get the result using your code 
"File size in bytes:14400950400
Example size in bytes:1000083
Number of examples:14399.755220316714".
And actually I have 14400 examples in my tfrecord file. Can I avoid decimal result?

Comment: How to get numbers of bytes that can be divided with no remainder instead of simply using int().